# oauth popup window is blank when using facebook JS library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

I am integrating facebook single signon using the facebook Javascript library. I am using localhost for testing my app. Here is the setup on facebook for the app -

Site URL: http://localhost/home/index/

Site Domain: localhost

App runs on port 80 of localhost

After the user logs in and authorizes the app in the popup window, the popup window goes blank. It does not redirect to my app  url which I have specified.

Comment: Any errors in the log? Does your user get authenticated? What URL are you on when you get the blank page?

Comment: yes, user gets authenticated. There is no error in the rails development.log. should i turn any other logs on? The main page is still at http://localhost and the popup window shows this url, which has user-id and token http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f14a66c4c0aaa06&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ffaad8d869cf30b&relation.....

Comment: Your redirect might not be set up properly, check the facebook settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using OmniAuth for my rails app to add Facebook login. It is a a perfect plugin for facebook authentication, very easy to use. You can look at the Railscast tutorial on how to use OmniAuth: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth